# Log number of keyboard hits

Tags: bash, shell, keyboard

How can I log a keyboard hit via shell script?
My aim is to log the number of keyboard hits of a login session on my Ubuntu system.

Note: I do not want to log the keystrokes itself, only the number of hits. So in the end it says:

```
94853 hits today.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Monitoring in X11 (Graphical Desktop) Session Only

In you're using the XInput layer (you probably are, if you're running a modern X) then `xinput test «keyboard-id»` (from the `xinput` package on Debian) will give pey press and release events. You can get the keyboard ID by running `xinput list`. You can also use the name.

```
xinput test 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard' | grep -c 'key press'
```

Note that when you pipe `xinput`, it has a fairly large buffer. So you may lose some keystrokes, unfortunately. You could use the XI2 API directly to avoid that, but that's not easy from shell.

You can fairly easily start your script as one of the login scripts in your desktop environment or from your `.xsession` file, depending. The `xinput` should exit when you log out, because it'll lose its X11 connection. So it's really easy to track when your session starts and ends.

### Monitoring System-wide (All Sessions, Even Text Mode)

Alternatively, if you want to monitor *all* keystrokes on the system, not just those in your X11 session, you can use the `input-events` (part of the input-utils package on Debian, at least). This must run as root. Use `lsinput` to find the right input device (happens to be 0 on my system) and then:

```
input-events 0 | grep -c 'EV_KEY.*pressed'
```

If you go this way, you'll have to figure out when your sessions start and end some way (e.g., peterph's dbus suggestion).

Comment: Kind of humorous to see modern and X in the same sentence, kind of like "prehistoric modern man" ;-)

Answer (score 4):

As Derobert mentioned, `xinput` can be used (`xinput --test-xi2` should work - you would need to count the lines containing `RawKeyPress`). However, you'd need to run your script as soon as your session starts and stop once it ends - so you'd probably want to watch a dbus session too.

Additionally, you would miss anything typed on virtual consoles - for that I'm afraid you'd need to write a kernel module, that would export its statistics somewhere in `/proc` or `/sys` - but it would include pretty much everything that goes into the computer.

Comment: FYI: In most desktops its fairly easy to know when the session starts—you can add log-in scripts that'll start with the session. When it stops is also easy, that's when the `xinput` will exit (from losing its X11 connection). I'll update my answer with this.

Comment: You shouldn't need a kernel module—see the `input-utils` package. Another thing to put in my answer :-P

Comment: Also, `xinput --test-xi2` pops up a window here, which is why I didn't use it.

Comment: @derobert bah, I completely forgot about `/dev/input` (which is what `input-utils` seem to use) :)